# Combining PHP Functions - Advanced Search?

Tags: php

I have to build an advanced search feature and some of it options are complex. For example:

- is Online
- have Comments
- etc

To get this information, I can't make direct database queries. So, I need to build functions to do this.

Let's say... the user selects 4 or 5 options - how can I combine multiple functions results?

It doesn't make sense to do something like:

```
if(is_Online() && have_Comments()...)
```

Because I don't know which or how many options are selected... so I think there should be some dynamic alternative?

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you make direct database queries? It seems to me like any other way would be incredibly slow if you've got a lot of data.

Comment: For example... to know if some user have comments would need to check the comments table and look for that user... is there not any field on the database that would directly tell me if have comments or not.

Comment: In that particular instance, it seems to me like you could use an `exists` subquery.

Comment: Are you asking if there any fields in the database to tell if they have comments or not, or stating there aren't? You need to edit your question and add a bit more detail.

Comment: There are no field telling if there is comments or not. Need to check the comments table and count for the user x.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to provide a better answer without more detail, but this might help you. The following assumes that your if statement will proceed when each checkbox is either left unchecked or when the logic associated with that checkbox returns true.

I would be inclined to store each function in an array and call them dynamically based on the name of the field you're looking at.

```
<?php

$resultCheckers = array(
   'is_Online' => function() { /* Is Online logic here */}, 
   'have_Comments' => function() { /* Have Comments logic here */}
);

function IsUncheckedOrHasValue($parameter)
{
   $result = true;
   //Check if user has checked the box for this parameter
   if(array_key_exists($parameter, $_POST))
   {
      //Check if this is a valid key in your $resultCheckers
      if(array_key_exists($parameter, $resultCheckers))
      {
         //Run the result Checker
         $result = $resultCheckers[$parameter]();
      } else {
         $result = false;
      }
   }
   return $result;
}


?>
```

Your if statement would look something like this:

```
if(IsUncheckedOrHasValue('is_Online') && IsUncheckedOrHasValue('have_Comments'))
{
...
}
```

Which is a bit laborious to read, so if you wanted you could abstract it further into it's own function like this:

```
function IsMatch()
{
    $isMatch = IsUncheckedOrHasValue('is_Online') && 
               IsUncheckedOrHasValue('have_Comments') &&
               IsUncheckedOrHasValue(...) &&
               IsUncheckedOrHasValue(...);

    return $isMatch;
}
```

So then your if statement would end up being

```
if(IsMatch())
{
...
}
```

NOTE: I'm a little confused that you're not passing any information about the result to your checking functions. Are you writing it Object Oriented and that information is available in the current object? Or perhaps you just omitted those extra parameters for brevity. In any event, I hope this helps you and it was fun to dip back into PHP after some time away from it :)